# My increment calculation does not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so on a button press, my code is supposed to increment the mooring by one until it get's to five, after it get's to five, it has to increment the pier by one, and then the mooring by one until it get's to five and then  increase the pier by one and then so on.

But what it does at the moment is, it increments the pier, then the mooring to 5, but after i click the button for it to increment again (where it should increment the pier to two and the mooring back to one) it crashes.

This is my code

```
//Setting the max value for Piers and Moorings
        public const int maxPiers = 6;
        public const int maxMoorings = 30;
        private static bool[,] reserveMooring = new bool[maxPiers, maxMoorings];

[WebMethod]
        public BoatResponse ReserveMooring(BoatRequest req)
        {
            var res = new BoatResponse();

            //if mooringCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxMoorings increment
            for (int mooringCalc = 0; mooringCalc < maxMoorings; mooringCalc++)
            {
                //if pierCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxPiers increment
                for (int pierCalc = 0; pierCalc < maxMoorings / maxPiers; mooringCalc++)
                {

                    if (!reserveMooring[pierCalc, mooringCalc])
                    {
                        reserveMooring[pierCalc, mooringCalc] = true;
                        res.Pier = (Pier)pierCalc;
                        res.Mooring = (Mooring)mooringCalc;
                        return res;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

the crash occurs here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var req = new BoatRequest();
            req.Name = txtName.Text;
            var client = new BoatReserveSoapClient();
            BoatResponse response = client.ReserveMooring(req);//error is on this line
```

and this is the BoatResponse

```
namespace NewBoatBookingApp
{

    public enum Pier
    {
        one,
        two,
        three,
        four,
        five,
        six
    }


    public enum Mooring
    { 
        one,
        two,
        three,
        four,
        five
    }

    public class BoatResponse
    {
        public Pier Pier;
        public Mooring Mooring;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '6' is not a valid value for NewBoatBookingApp.Mooring.
```

Comment: You've set `maxMoorings` to 30. There are only five options in the `Mooring` enum?

Comment: there are 5 per pier, so 30 in total.

Comment: You may want to reset the count at each pier then because again, there are only 5 options in the enum :)

Comment: Doesn't feel like a good use of enums to me. You might want consider using classes rather then enums. Have a pier class and a mooring class. Each pier can then have a list of moorings as well as other properties you may need. For instance, you cannot add location data to a pier in the solution you have or any property for that matter. Instances of piers can then be stored in a list which will be much easier to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty clear - you're trying to assign a `Mooring` with a value of 6 when it only goes from 1 to 5.

It looks like your `Piers` and `Moorings` loops are backwards?

```
//if mooringCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxMoorings increment
for (int pierCalc = 0; pierCalc < maxPiers; pierCalc++)
{
    //if pierCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxPiers increment
    for (int mooringCalc = 0; mooringCalc < maxMoorings / maxPiers; mooringCalc++)
```

Comment: like I commented above, there are 5 moorings per pier, and there are 6 piers, is it not possible to have it NOT go above 5? each pier only goes up to 5 moorings.

Comment: My second loop should go from 0 to 5 (30/6).

Comment: This fixed it, thank you, it increments properly now. Will give correct answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop in your method has a condition

```
mooringCalc < maxMoorings
```

Where you have `maxMoorings` set to `30` and your enum has only 6 values. So when you do:

```
res.Mooring = (Mooring)mooringCalc; //here mooringCalc is 6
```

You get an exception for value `6` since the enum only has 5 items. Hence the error

> '6' is not a valid value for NewBoatBookingApp.Mooring.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are approaching this in quite a complicated manner...

If I understand you correctly, you have 30 moorings, and they are located on piers 1 to 6.

Why do you not just treat your moorings as one continous set, find an empty one, and then calculate on which pier that one is?

```
//Setting the max value for Piers and Moorings
    public const int mooringsPerPier = 5;
    public const int maxMoorings = 30;
    private staticbool[] reserveMooring = new bool[maxMoorings];

[WebMethod]
    public BoatResponse ReserveMooring(BoatRequest req)
    {
        int mooring = Array.IndexOf(reserveMooring, false);
        if (mooring < 0)
        {
          return null;
        }
        reserveMooring[mooring] = true;
        return new BoatResponse()
        {
           Pier = (Pier)(int(mooring / mooringsPerPier)),
           Mooring = (Mooring)(int(mooring % mooringsperPier)
        };
    }
```

Just the same, i would lose the two enums the way you are using them here, unless they will get useful names later on :)